# Jquery validation is valid although have error in remote validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have jquery validation.  It works fine except checking the remote.  It seems it check the remote after the form is already submitted.

Here's my code:

```
$('#m_login_signup_submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let btn = $(this);
    let form = $('#register_form');

    form.validate({
        rules: {
            fullname: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: '/account/check-email',
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            },
            password_confirmation: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: '#register_password'
            },
            agree: {
                required: true
            }
        },

        messages:{
            email:{remote:'Email already registered'}
        },
    });

    if (form.valid()) {

        btn.addClass('m-loader m-loader--right m-loader--light').attr('disabled', true);
        form.ajaxSubmit({
            url: '/account/register',
            success: function (response, status, xhr, $form) {
                let result = $.parseJSON(response);
                if (result.status === 'success') {

                    form.clearForm();
                    form.validate().resetForm();

                }else{
                    showErrorMsg(form, 'danger', result.message);
                }
            }
        });
    }

});
```

How can I can I make the form is submitted only when all the validation is passed including the remote one?

Comment: Does it make sense to ask the server if data is ok and then submit it to the server? Anyway server needs to validate it in the register process.

Comment: well, it supposes when clicked it check the remote then if it not valid it prevent the form for being submitted right? or am i missing something here?

Comment: Sure, I think the code is intended as you described. I'm just wondering if it makes sense to ask the server first to validate and then submit the form. Anyway the server needs to validate the form when it is submitted.

Comment: it possible if using ajax. but the matter is this code suppose to be halted from being submitted until all the field was checked and valid.

Comment: Are you not going to show us the relevant HTML or the server-side code at `/account/check-email`?

Comment: @Sparky if i do that i can't post the question will full with the code.

Comment: it just normal html and the server side just return echo 'true' or 'false'.

Comment: "normal html"??  There are all kinds of things that you could be doing wrong in the markup.  Even if you have perfect HTML, you should be helping us to help you by not making us re-write the code to make a demo.

Comment: The problem is also very unclear... is it an issue of the remote taking too long to get a response... or does it just not check anything until after the submit?  It's going to be almost impossible for us to help you if we don't know the problem in great detail, since we don't have access to your server and you refuse to show us all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think you might have better success putting your Ajax inside of the `submitHandler` callback of the `.validate()` method rather than doing it externally.  [According to the docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler), this is *"the right place to submit a form via Ajax"*.
2. Do NOT put `.validate()` inside of a `click` handler.  The `.validate()` method is used for initializing the plugin on your form and does not need to be called every time the button is clicked.  You call it once and the button (*must be `type="submit"`*) click is automatically captured by the plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#register_form').validate({
        rules: {
            fullname: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: '/account/check-email',
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            },
            password_confirmation: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: '#register_password'
            },
            agree: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages:{
            email:{remote:'Email already registered'}
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#m_login_signup_submit').addClass('m-loader m-loader--right m-loader--light').attr('disabled', true);
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                url: '/account/register',
                success: function (response, status, xhr, $form) {
                    let result = $.parseJSON(response);
                    if (result.status === 'success') {
                        $(form).clearForm();
                        $(form).validate().resetForm();
                    } else {
                        showErrorMsg(form, 'danger', result.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: i already change my code as your answer but still not change.

Comment: @Ying, does the remote take too long to get a response... or does it just not check anything until after the submit?  These are things you should be looking at from your JavaScript console.

Comment: @Ying, did you really try my solution?  Did you remove `.valid()` method and the `click` handler?  [There is a known issue where invoking `.valid()` seems to ignore the `remote` method](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/1045).  Since the problem description in your OP is so vague, I'm not even sure if this is could be the issue.

Comment: ah i'm so sorry i put the HTML and JS here: https://codepen.io/exodia6666/pen/ERVGxj

Comment: when i click the submit button it send the form, and then alert was triggered and then after that the warning about email already registered is showed. it has no delay. it work, but after the form already submitted.

Comment: @Ying, if you tried my solution, you would have to put a `type="submit"` on your submit button or nothing would happen.

Comment: @Ying, what "alert" is triggered?  I see no alerts in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172315/discussion-between-ying-and-sparky).

Comment: seem like you right i try your code and seem like it has a problem with lasspass google extensions, i disable it and try your suggestion and it work. thanks.